# communicate unrelated components in Angular 13

Tags: angular, components, communication

In my Angular application I have a navbar containing two tabs: 'home' and 'new tab' . On the Home page I make a series of calls and get a series of data that I need to use in the 'new tab' tab , but they are not child and parent components. how could this be done ?

Comment: You'll want to look into `Services`, ie https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67877974/how-to-use-the-same-instance-of-an-object-in-2-different-components-angular/67878351#67878351